# put in a frame image taken from the camera or on own camera

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm studying, and I'm trying to develop an application I have in mind.

But, I'm trying a way to put a background image or a frame for a captured photo or even at the time the camera is triggered.

I am developing for android using angular with ionic framework.

I do not know if it's possible, but I thank you! O/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.Apply some css rules for `image` tag after capturing.

**1.Capture image**

First add the **`Camera`** plugin using the command

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="takePhoto()">Capture</button>
<li ng-repeat="i in myImage">
    <img ng-src="{{baseURL+i}}">
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 75,
        targetWidth: 320,
        targetHeight: 320,
        destinationType: 0,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        $scope.imgURI = imageData;
        $scope.myImage.push($scope.imgURI);
        $scope.$apply();

    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

};
```

**[Refer](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/)**

**2.Save photo after capture**

If you want to save this photo in your storage.Please add **`file`** plugin also,

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {
    if (window.cordova) {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            cameraDirection: 1,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
            $scope.imgURI = imagePath;
            //Grab the file name of the photo in the temporary directory
            var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
            //Create a new name for the photo
            var d = new Date(),
                n = d.getTime(),
                newFileName = n + ".jpg";
            //Move the file to permanent storage
            $cordovaFile.moveFile(cordova.file.tempDirectory, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
                //success.nativeURL will contain the path to the photo in permanent storage, do whatever you wish with it, e.g:
                //createPhoto(success.nativeURL);

            }, function(error) {
                //an error occured
            });

        }, function(error) {
            //An error occured
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: @FelipeLopes Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Simple !

```js
function takePicture() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {

    // imageURI is the URL of the image that we can use for
    // an <img> element or backgroundImage.

  }, function(err) {

    // Ruh-roh, something bad happened

  }, cameraOptions);
}
```

Read More : http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/